# My Ipega Demon Z PG-9129 controller is not working via USB cable on PC

Tags: controllers, windows, pcsx2, silent-hill-series

Hi **I was trying to connect my Ipega Demon Z controller via Scp toolkit with cable that was with controller** to my PC here is what did it show:

[image: Trying to connect Ipega Demon Z via Scp Toolkit]

**I wanted to play Silent Hill Homecoming with it which works fine with my Dualshock3 via Scp Toolkit but doesn't work with Ipega Demon Z(fake Xbox controller).**

It beeps everytime I connect it indicating it connected to PC also it shows in plugged devices :

[image: It connect to PC]

**I also tried to connect it to PCSX2 emuator but id didn't work there either.(I am testing it with Windows 11)**

This is how it show in **SCP Toolkit when I plug my Original PS3 controller into PC** :

[image: PS3 Controller is connected via SCP Toolkit]

Do you have any suggestions what program should I use to make it work with Ipega Demon Z controller or maybe how to use it with Scp Toolkit?

Thank you for your answers and advices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **photo from user guide about how to connect GAMEPAD IPEGA PG-9129 to PC**:

[image]

All you need to do is go to  :

START -> type in Bluetooth -> Find Settings for Bluetooth devices and check if there is your Device connected.

Then you need to go to :

- **[www.x360ce.com](http://www.x360ce.com)** and download program from there
- I downloaded **New 4.17.15.0 • 2020-11-15 FOR ALL GAMES**
- **Wait for program to download and extract it somewhere for example into folder where all your games are located **
- open it

It should look like this :

[image: x360ce program opened]

Then you will need to **click on Add game**. It will show all your devices and choose your desired Gamepad then it automatically enable mapping of your controller as on image.

**I recommed you to keep running this program in background.**

**EDIT** ***It works with Windows games as well as with pcsx2 emulator games***

**TESTED WITH :** *GAMEPAD IPEGA PG-9129*

Comment: I wonder why you needed to do all this. PCSX2 should be able to use XInput compatible gamepads without extra software. Your gamepad is XInput compatible so it should already work in Windows without additional drivers. ScpToolkit is the wrong tool, it's a driver for PS3/PS4 controllers only. x360ce is taking your Xbox controller and using it to simulate an Xbox controller, unnecessary. Maybe you just need to switch your gamepad to XInput mode?

Comment: @nondebug Thanks for your opinion. I wonder why too but it was only way I could have make it work. Probably issue with drivers for that controller because it is marked as Wireless controler and also it is like universal controller for Andoid , IOS , PC , PlayStation and Xbox